# Perspective of energy expended by a power supply

Tags: voltage, batteries

Electrical Energy

Example No1:

What is the terminal voltage of a battery that expends 135 joules of energy to move 15 coulombs of charge around an electrical circuit?

[image]

Then we can see in this example that every coulomb of charge possesses an energy of 9 joules.

One joule is equivalent to applying a force of one newton along one meter. Does this mean a 9V battery can apply a force of 135 newtons on an object along one metre? One newton is the acceleration of 1kg mass at 1m/s^2.

That would make a 9V battery is capable of accelerating an object of 1kg at 135m/s^2 across 1m.

That's a bit exaggerated, don't you think? Is this really equivalent?

Comment: why not? ... you are forgetting about the fact that the 9 V battery that you are talking about can supply infinite current when shorted ... it would vaporize a crescent wrench

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a little 9-volt alkaline battery *does* store between 10 and 20 kilojoules. Consider the [18650 Li-ion cell](https://commonsensehome.com/18650-battery/), which stores ~2 ampere-hours (A-h) at a nominal 3.7 volts over the discharge cycle.

2 A-h = 7,200 ampere-seconds, x 3.7 volts = 26,640 watt-seconds ([26,640 Joules (J)](https://www.unitconverters.net/energy/joule-to-watt-second.htm)).

The [muzzle energy](https://military-history.fandom.com/wiki/Muzzle_energy) of a 7.62 × 51 mm rifle bullet is ~3,800 J, only one *seventh* that of the venerable 18650 cell. The somewhat larger [.50 Browning Machine Gun BMG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.50_BMG) has a muzzle energy of ~18,000 J, roughly 2/3 that stored in the 18650.

Normally these storage devices release their energy over a period of hours, or *years*, so instantaneous power is low -- though there is the occasional [Rapid Unplanned Disassembly (RUD)](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/10022/who-coined-the-phrase-rapid-unscheduled-disassembly) of batteries...